# Inteliij IDEA : Gatling getting j.l.NullPointerException while running simple script

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gatling, scala-gatling

While I as executing below scala code  as Gatling script from Intellij IDEA Ultimate

```
import java.net.URI
import java.util
import java.util.{Collections, Optional}

import com.tools.RequestSigner
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

class CheckResponseCode extends Simulation {

  val httpConf = http.baseUrl("https://localhost:8080/")
    .header("Accept", "application/json")
  val jsonFileFeeder = jsonFile("data\\request.json")
  val scn = scenario("get data")
    .feed(jsonFileFeeder)
    .exec(http("Get data")
      .put("/test1")
      .sign(new com.tools.RequestSigner()
        .check(jsonPath("$..operation").saveAs("operationId"))
      .check(status.is(202))
      .check( bodyString.saveAs( "RESPONSE_DATA" ) ))
  .exec( session => {
    println("Some Restful Service Response Body:")
    println(session("RESPONSE_DATA").as[String])
    session
  })




  setUp(
    scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
  ).protocols(httpConf)


}
```

I get to see below in the result :

```
---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------
> j.l.NullPointerException                                            1 (100.0%)
```

What can be reason behind these and where can I find th detailed stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

In whatever [logback appender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) is configured in your `logback.xml` configuration file, typically in the console.